# how display more lines in wordpress-the_excerpt()

Tags: wordpress

**Hai,
          I am designing a blog in wordpress. I am facing problem when I display the topic through  the_excerpt().It only display 3 lines and then Continue Link comes.But I want each post will
come with 6-10 line and the continue-> link.how I can increase the line numbers.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an [excerpt_length](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length) filter to your theme before you call [the_except](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt).

In the filter you sepcify how many words you want in your except (you can only specify words, not lines).

An example:

```
function my_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 120;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');
```

If you REALLY want to filter on a certain number of lines, you could call [get_the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) and extract the number of lines you wanted - but make sure you filter the content to ensure nothing unwanted makes it into your blog.

Comment: Okay ,Well.. In my wp-includes/formatting.php their is already "excerpt_length" as 55.I change it to 150. still it's not working....check the some code given bellow of formatting.php.php

function wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
 $raw_excerpt = $text;
 if ( '' == $text ) {
  $text = get_the_content('');

  $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

  $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
  $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
  $text = strip_tags($text);
  $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);


one more Q? is that

Which file I have to add the
my_excerpt_length($length){}

Comment: @James, You should really not be changing wp-includes/formatting.php  as this is part of the base wordpress install.

You can make changes to your theme -  (your probably using the default theme at the moment). In the wordpress theme editor Administration -> Design - > Theme Editor (or another editor if you prefer)  Add the code above inside some <?php ?> braces and this will do what you want.